# GeoServer wind speed with WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms, scale, zoom

I have a GeoTIFF layer with spatial resolution of 3 km with two bands with wind speed components (u,v). I want to display these datasets with `RasterAsPointCollection` plugin with arrows size and direction adjusted. By following [this example](https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/currents.html) I managed to show data, but It fails to group them when changing zoom levels. I believe settings have to be related to `wms_scale_denominator`. I tried different combinations of parameters in this section but no success. Here is complete SLD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
   <Name>currents</Name>
   <UserStyle>
     <Title>currents</Title>
     <FeatureTypeStyle>
      <Transformation>
         <ogc:Function name="ras:RasterAsPointCollection">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
               <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>interpolation</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>InterpolationBilinear</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
               <ogc:Function name="env">
                 <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
               </ogc:Function>
           <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>50000</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>100000</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>500000</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>5000000</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>0.1</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>10000000</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>0.05</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>20000000</ogc:Literal>
           <ogc:Literal>0.02</ogc:Literal>          
         </ogc:Function>
            </ogc:Function>
   </ogc:Function>
      </Transformation>
      <Rule>
        <Title>Heading</Title>
        <PointSymbolizer>
         <Graphic>
           <Mark>
             <WellKnownName>extshape://narrow</WellKnownName>
             <Fill>
               <CssParameter name="fill">
                <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                  <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                    <ogc:Add>
                     <ogc:Mul>
                       <ogc:PropertyName>GRAY_INDEX</ogc:PropertyName>
                       <ogc:PropertyName>GRAY_INDEX</ogc:PropertyName>
                     </ogc:Mul>
                     <ogc:Mul>
                       <ogc:PropertyName>Band2</ogc:PropertyName>
                       <ogc:PropertyName>Band2</ogc:PropertyName>
                     </ogc:Mul>
                    </ogc:Add>
                  </ogc:Function>
                  <ogc:Literal>#0000FF</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>#0033FF</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>#0066FF</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>#0099FF</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>#00CCFF</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>#00FFFF</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
               </CssParameter>
            </Fill>
           </Mark>
           <Size>
             <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                <!-- Value to transform -->
               <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                 <ogc:Add>
                  <ogc:Mul>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>GRAY_INDEX</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>GRAY_INDEX</ogc:PropertyName>
                  </ogc:Mul>
                  <ogc:Mul>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>Band2</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>Band2</ogc:PropertyName>
                  </ogc:Mul>
                 </ogc:Add>
               </ogc:Function>
                  <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.1</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.2</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.4</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.5</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.6</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>14</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.7</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.8</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>0.9</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>1.0</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>22</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>1.1</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>25</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
           </Size>
           <Rotation>
               <ogc:Function name="toDegrees">
                <ogc:Function name="atan2">
                   <ogc:PropertyName>GRAY_INDEX</ogc:PropertyName>
                   <ogc:PropertyName>Band2</ogc:PropertyName>
                </ogc:Function>
               </ogc:Function>
           </Rotation>
         </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
     </FeatureTypeStyle>
   </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

And here are sample outputs with different resolutions:

1:150000

[image]

1:300000

[image]

How can I adjust arrow numbers ( density) on changing zoom levels?